# Django: how to render data on users dashboard

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django. I am working on a project where admin can assign a team to manager and that team should be viewed on that manager's dashboard. i.e. when ever admin click the assign button then it will be seen in that manager's dashboard. But i don't know how can i do this.

here is my .html page where admin can see the name of all the managers

```
<div class="body table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-hover">
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>S No.</th>
       <th>COMPANY NAME</th>
        <th>TEAM MEMBER</th>
         <th>EMAIL</th>
          <th>ASSIGN TEAM</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
        <tbody>
         {%for team in object%}
           <tr>
             <form id="form_id" method="POST" action = "{% url 'accept' %}">
               {% csrf_token %}
              <th scope="row"> {{ forloop.counter }}</th>
               <td>{{team.company_name}}</td>
                <td>{{team.team_member}}</td>
                 <td>{{team.email}}</td>
                  <td>
                     <select name="manager_{{manager.id}}">
                      {% for manager in managers %}
                        <option value ="{{manager.id}}">{{manager.name}}</option>
                      {% endfor %}                                   
                       </select>
                   </td>
                     <td>
                         <input class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-round waves-effect" type="submit" value="Assign">
                                    </td>
                    </tr>
                     {% endfor %}
                     </tbody>
                    </table>
```

and here is my views.py from where admin can see the managers name and all the info

```
def accept(request):
 obj= Create_Team.objects.filter(status='Accept') 
 managers = manager.objects.all()
 if request.method == 'POST':
   acc = manager()
   manager_id = int(request.POST.get('manager', 1))
   acc.manager = manager.objects.get(pk=manager_id)

     return render(request, "admin/accept.html", {"object": obj,  "managers": managers})
```

here is my views.py from where managers page is rendering

```
def supervisor(request):
 return render(request, 'manager/index-3.html')
```

here is my model.py file for manager

```
class manager(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
 designation = models.CharField(max_length= 500)
 class Meta:
    permissions = [
        ("edit_task", "can edit the task"),
    ]

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

i want that whenever admin can select a manager and then that team will be showed in that manager's dashboard. Here is the image of the admin page where he can see the name of all the manager.[image: here is the image]

Comment: How is this different from your previous question?

Comment: which previous question you are referring

Comment: now i have to assign that team to manager

Comment: please help me if you can